# Calculate Average Ride Time in Sheets

Tags: time, average, spreadsheet

I have a table with details about bike rides in a certain city. Table details include station, start time, stop time, etc. I want to know the average ride time for all rides.

I've used =TEXT(stoptime-starttime,"h:mm:ss") to find the time spent per ride. Now I tried using the AVERAGE function to find the average ride time but I keep ending a Div/0 error.

Comment: You haven't even told us what spreadsheet you are using!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.